# What is the difference between PHPGraphLib and JpGraph?

Tags: php, graph, charts

I am trying to generate simple bar charts to be displayed on a website. I am looking at [PHPGraphLib](http://www.ebrueggeman.com/phpgraphlib/) and [JpGraph](http://jpgraph.net/). They seem fairly comparable and with proper configuration they can probably produce nearly identical charts. Is there a reason to choose one over the other? Are there are any real differences between the two? Are there alternatives I may be overlooking?

Comment: Semi-related: Does anybody know of any PHP graph libraries that -are- free for commercial use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPGraphLib looks to be more light wieght, and not quite as capable as JpGraph.  If you just look at the examples and the documentation, you can see how much more JpGraph does.  If your goal is to be lightweight and you don't need the extras JpGraph offers, then go with PHPGraphLib.  If you want to have a lot of flexibility in the graphs you can generate, go with JpGraph.  I have used JpGraph for a ton of things, and its very versatile, and you can figure out how to do anything using the huge number of examples they include with the source.

Answer (score 1):

jpGraph has far more capabilities than PHPGraphLib. On the other hand, PHPGraphLib is a lot easier to install and very fast. In fact, it is the only one that I was able to get to work immediately. It consists of only three files. I am still struggling with jpGraph and some truetype fonts that it cannot find. If PHPGraphLib has enough features for you, by all means, run with it. I wish I could.
Both of them are free for personal use, and a few hundred dollars for unlimited servers. Pretty good deal, and I think the developers deserve getting paid what they charge.